# Setting spinner values by choosing from popupwindow

Tags: android, spinner, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment, android-popupwindow

The image shows the top spinner and bottom popup

[image]

How to keep spinner and  a popup displayed together where spinner values are set by scrolling items on popup?

currently, when we click on bottom popup, the spinner gets dismissed and vice versa.

please look at the attached image

Comment: not getting your point what are you trying to do so please explain your question briefly.

Comment: so you need a spinner on place of location (in your image) and if `loc_spinner` expanded when a pop will come out with multiple selection if user selects value from the popup it will be added in the spinner. Right?

Comment: @DevendraSingh: you are correct.  when user clicks on the spinner item 'location", the bottom window pops up and user selects value from this popup. that value gets updated in the spinner item. (i.e spinner's drop-down and the bottom popup both should stay visible and should not get dissmissed  on clicking on each other.  but both of them can get dissmissed on clicking on anywhere on the screen)

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by creating a transparent LinearLayout that contains 2 children to represent top popup menu and bottom popup menu. this layout is displayed in fullscreen as a overlay on clicking of the top filter icon. this overlay layout is dismissed(set visibility to gone) on clicking anywhere outside of those 2 children.